# Repetir codigo php si se encuentra una coincidencia en base de datos MySQL

Tags: php

Lo que necesito hacer que es al crear un `randomstring` con php ese se consulte en la base de datos y si ya existe se cree uno nuevo desde mi script de php, sin que el usuario tenga que presionar de nuevo el botón, este es mi código de php.

```
function generateRandomString($length)
{
    return substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
}
$linkAcortar=generateRandomString(4);

$sqlClave = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE claveLink=?");
$sqlClave->bind_param('s', $linkAcortar);
$sqlClave->execute();
$resClave   = $sqlClave->get_result();
$datosClave = $resClave->fetch_assoc();

if ($resClave->num_rows >= 1) {
    // aqui se tiene que generar un codigo nuevo si en dado caso se encuentra en la base de datos
    // y si el nuevo generado tambien se encuentra generar otro hasta que no se repita
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Meté toda la lógica dentro de un [`while`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php) o [`do-while`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.do.while.php). Dentro del mismo tenés que generar el string (cosa que no veo en tu código) y hacer la consulta. Hasta que `num_rows` no sea igual a 0, no salís.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar un `while(true)` o una bandera y romper el bucle una vez que se cumpla la condición, te dejo un ejemplo básico intentando modificar tu código lo menos posible:

```
$sqlClave = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE claveLink=?");

while(true){
    // obtenemos el link a acortar, desconozco como lo haces
    $linkAcortar = bin2hex(random_bytes(5));

    $sqlClave->bind_param('s', $linkAcortar);
    $sqlClave->execute();
    $resClave   = $sqlClave->get_result();
    $datosClave = $resClave->fetch_assoc();

    if ($resClave->num_rows >= 1) {
        // si existe continuas a la siguiente iteracion
        continue;
    }
    // con break rompes el bucle y continua el script
    break;
}
```

Comment: No le veo el sentido a poner un While con un (true) 'a piñon' . ¿Tiene alguna ventaja respecto a  poner dentro del `if` una bandera y que el `while` pregunte por el valor de esa bandera?

Comment: Son distintas formas de programar. Podria haber usado tambien un Do While, asi que no tiene nada de malo ese TRUE en el While. Con el TRUE simplemente mantiene el ciclo vivo hasta cuando quiera romperlo "break"

Comment: Son formas totalmente equivalentes ? o de pende del caso una es mejor que otra? y si es si ¿En que me baso para elegir una forma u otroa?

Answer (score 3):

Aunque la otra respuesta es "correcta", veo varios errores de forma en la misma.

Si usamos `rand()`, este esta acotado a una determinada cantidad de valores. El md5 de cada uno de esos valores sera el mismo y entonces en realidad nuestro sistema solo va a permitir por ejemplo 32767 valores ([fuente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php))

En lugar de rand, utilizaria [random_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.random-bytes.php) y lo haria exactamente como dice el ejemplo.

usar while(true) y luego break y continue, es como arruinar la logica del sistema... porque si sabemos que vamos a salir no ponemos directamente la condición que corresponde?

Yo escribiria ese mismo codigo, pero con algunas salvedades.

```
$sqlClave = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE claveLink=?");
$valida = false;
while(!$valida){
    //md5 random
    $linkAcortar = bin2hex(random_bytes(5));
    $sqlClave->bind_param('s', $linkAcortar);
    $sqlClave->execute();
    $resClave   = $sqlClave->get_result();
    $datosClave = $resClave->fetch_assoc();
    $valida = $resClave->num_rows >= 1;
}
```

Comment: Utilice `rand()` por poner algo rapido ya que en la pregunta no indica como genera $linkAcortado, solo dice que genera un `randomstring` ¿?. Pero no por que lo fuese a utilizar. Como añadido, deberia de pasar `random_bytes()` por `bin2hex()` por ejemplo para tener un string, algo como `bin2hex(random_bytes(5))`

Comment: Buen punto @Xerif, me olvide de esa funcion. Pero ya que contestamos, hagamoslo bien y completo ;)

Comment: perdon por no poner como genero el randomString lo genero son str_shuffle

Answer (score 1):

no me parece muy correcto el planteamiento inicial. Seria importante saber cuantos registros va a almacenar la tabla `t_links`. En el primer ejemplo se hace un "aleatorio" de 4 caracteres, por lo que no va a haber muchas combinaciones y a la larga vas a hacer muchas consultas de lectura inutiles de la bbdd. Yo te planteo otras dos opciones:

1.- leer los registros `claveLink` de la tabla y meterlos en un array. Luego generar cadenas aleatorias y comprobar que no existan en el array.

```
$sqlClave = $conexion->prepare("SELECT claveLink FROM t_links");
$sqlClave->execute();
$res      = $sqlClave->get_result();
$claves   = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

en $claves tendras un array con todas las claves existentes.

ahora en php generamos cadenas hasta que NO existan en el array:

```
$count = 0:
do {
  $count++;
  $clave = generateRandomString(4);
  $existe = in_array($clave, $claves);
} while ($existe && $count<100);
if($existe) {
   // error generando aleatorio
}
```

Asi a la larga te va a ahorrar consultas de lectura a la bbdd. El $count es para que no te lo intente mas de 100 veces y evitar bloquearte dentro del bucle (que podria llegar a pasar)

2.- cambia tu generador de claves, concatenando algo continuo (como microtime).

```
function generateRandomString()
{
    return md5(
      str_shuffle(
        "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
      )
      .microtime()
    );
}
```

tienes una parte aleatoria (el str_shuffle), y lo concatenas con algo continuo como el microtime (fecha mas hora con microsegundos). De esta manera tu cadena es aleatoria y siempre es distinta a la generada anteriormente.

En el ejemplo he puesto un md5 de esa cadena (claro que existen colisiones de cadena) asi que quizas habria que cambiarlo por sha u otro algoritmo. Lo que interesa es la idea de un aleatorio+continuo